# When is it a good idea to use a vb.net Module

Tags: vb.net, class, module, shared

Some of my co-workers make extensive use of the VB.net concept of Modules. Unfortunately, I just don't 'get it'. I see no benefit in using modules over shared classes. Am I missing something? When would it be preferable to use a module? Or am I (as I do quite often in this language) 'just not getting it'?

Comment: You cannot declare a class as shared in VB.Net. Modules are fairly equal to classes that only have shared members and functions, a private constructor and where only one instance exists from application start to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.net a module is a shared class. When they are compiled they are given a private constructor and methods set to shared.

There are some times when you are forced to use modules by the compiler (in the same way static classes are in C#) such as for extension methods which can not be created in side a VB.Net class.

By using modules for your helper methods you will make it easier to convert them over to extension methods later and restrict others from adding any instance methods or constructors.

That said they are a hang over from VB6 that did not support full OO programming and beyond standalone helper methods they would not widely be used.

Comment: Completely agree. The only time I use modules is when I need to make extension methods. If I need to make a static class I instead make a regular class with static methods and a private constructor. I'm pretty sure that modules only exist to help upgrade VB6 projects to VB.Net and as such I consider them the same as REM - technically available but shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Chris: If modules were in any way replaced or deprecated or unnecessary or redundant, they'd have faded in usage much as REM did. Instead, they're now *required* in order to do extension methods, because a module fills a particular niche in VB.net that isn't filled by any other unit of code defined by the language. They will only really be redundant when you can say `Public Shared Class Foo`, but even then it's just (ugly) semantics -- a module and a static class would do the same thing.  IMO modules and classes *should* be declared differently, as they have entirely different purposes.

Comment: I'd say that "static classes" are ugliness from languages that didn't have the concept of a "module" -- and aside from temporary use to port some code over, *they're* what shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

A module is essentially the same as a shared class.  The major difference is that in a module, there's no need for all the extra "shared"s, cause everything's implicitly shared.  If you have no instance data and are just using the class as a kind of namespace for functions, then it's a better idea (IMO) to use a module instead and make that clear.